# Directx11 Texture2D formats

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

For some reason, I cannot specify `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` format when creating a texture 2d in directx11. I can do it just fine in OpenGL, however. It also works fine when using `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`. I am using these textures as rendertargets for the gbuffer.

```
    // create gbuffer textures/rendertargets
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    textureDesc.Width = swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width;
    textureDesc.Height = swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;    <----- dosn't like this; returns E_INVALIDARG
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;

    for (uint32_t index = 0; index < GBuffer::GBUFFER_NUM_RENDERTARGETS; index++) 
    {
        DXCALL(device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &mGeometryTextures[index]));
        DXCALL(device->CreateRenderTargetView(mGeometryTextures[index], NULL, &mRenderTargets[index]));
    }
```

Why cant I use `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` when creating a 2d texture in directx 11?

I do not need the extra float in my texture, hence I'd rather have just three elements rather than four.

Comment: Which [feature level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx) is your hardware?  You can use "DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT" on Feature Level 9.2 or later or "DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT" on Feature Level 9.3 or later. Specific operations may not be allowed for "R32G32B32_FLOAT" as these are optional for even current generation DirectX hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all hardware supports using `R32G32B32_FLOAT` as a render-target and shader-resource (it's optional).  You can verify whether the hardware supports the format for those uses by calling [`CheckFormatSupport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476498(v=vs.85).aspx).  If it is succeeding on the same hardware with OpenGL, this likely means OpenGL is padding the resource out to the full 4-channel variant behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

`DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` support for render targets is optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471325(v=vs.85).aspx#RenderTarget

If you think that this format should be supported by your device then turn on debug output as MooseBoys suggested. This should explain why you're getting `E_INVALIDARG`.

Comment: Can you suggest a better format to use in this case? Im using it for gbuffer textures such as diffuse, normals, position, etc

Comment: @KaiserJohaan You should use `R32G32B32A32` and manually pack/unpack the channels (e.g. `o0.xyz = pos.xyz; o0.w = tex.u; o1.x = tex.v; o1.yzw = norm;`)